# Subset between multiple dates in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I have the following data:

```
SN,CY,Y,M,D,lat,lon,cat
198305,5,1983,8,5,0,9.1,140.7,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,5,6,9.3,140.5,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,5,12,9.6,139.9,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,5,18,9.9,139.4,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,0,10.2,138.8,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,6,11,138.1,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,12,11.8,137.3,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,18,12.4,136.4,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,7,0,12.8,135.8,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,7,6,13.6,134.7,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,7,12,14.4,133.9,"Cat2"
198305,5,1983,8,7,18,15,133.5,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,8,0,15.8,132.8,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,8,6,16.3,132.4,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,8,12,17.1,132,"Cat5"
198305,5,1983,8,8,18,17.4,131.4,"Cat5"
198305,5,1983,8,9,0,17.8,130.8,"Cat5"
198305,5,1983,8,9,6,18.1,130.7,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,9,12,18.7,130.3,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,9,18,18.9,130.4,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,10,0,19.2,130.4,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,10,6,19.5,130.4,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,10,12,19.9,130.5,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,10,18,20.1,130.5,"Cat3"
198305,5,1983,8,11,0,20.6,130.7,"Cat3"
198305,5,1983,8,11,6,21.2,130.8,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,11,12,21.6,130.7,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,11,18,22,130.6,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,12,0,22.5,130.7,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,12,6,22.9,130.8,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,12,12,23.4,131.2,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,12,18,23.9,131.5,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,13,0,24.6,131.8,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,13,6,24.9,132.2,"Cat3"
198306,6,1983,8,13,6,19.2,119.4,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,13,12,25.4,132.6,"Cat3"
198306,6,1983,8,13,12,19.4,120.2,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,13,18,26.1,133,"Cat3"
198306,6,1983,8,13,18,19.6,120.8,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,14,0,26.6,133.3,"Cat3"
198306,6,1983,8,14,0,19.8,121.5,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,14,6,27.2,133.5,"Cat3"
198306,6,1983,8,14,6,19.9,122.7,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,14,12,27.6,133.5,"Cat3"
198306,6,1983,8,14,12,19.9,124.4,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,14,18,28.1,133.5,"Cat2"
198306,6,1983,8,14,18,20.2,126.2,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,15,0,28.5,133.6,"Cat2"
198306,6,1983,8,15,0,21,128.3,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,15,6,29.1,134.1,"Cat2"
198306,6,1983,8,15,6,22,130,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,15,12,29.5,134.3,"Cat2"
198305,5,1983,8,15,18,30,134.8,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,16,0,31.1,135.1,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,16,6,31.8,135.8,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,16,12,32.7,136.5,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,16,18,33.8,137,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,17,0,34.6,137.3,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,17,6,35.1,138.1,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,17,6,15.2,140.1,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,17,12,35.6,139.4,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,17,12,15.4,139,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,17,18,15.4,138.1,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,18,0,15.2,137.2,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,18,6,15,136.3,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,18,12,15.2,135.3,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,18,18,15.6,134.5,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,19,0,15.9,133.8,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,19,6,16.1,133.2,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,19,12,16.3,132.8,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,19,18,16.5,132.4,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,20,0,16.9,132.2,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,20,6,17.4,132.5,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,20,12,18,133,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,20,18,18.7,133.7,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,21,0,19.3,134.7,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,21,6,20,135.6,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,21,12,20.7,136.3,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,21,18,21.4,137.1,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,22,0,22.2,137.9,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,22,6,23.2,138.7,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,22,12,23.8,140.1,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,22,18,24.2,141.6,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,23,0,24.9,142.6,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,23,6,25.4,143.1,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,23,12,25.8,143.5,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,23,18,25.5,144,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,24,0,25.1,144.3,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,24,6,25.3,144.7,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,24,12,25.8,144.7,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,24,18,26.2,144.1,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,25,0,26.5,143.4,"TS"
198308,8,1983,8,25,6,27.1,142.8,"TS"
198309,9,1983,8,25,6,25.5,128.1,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,25,12,27.9,141.8,"TS"
198309,9,1983,8,25,12,25.6,128.8,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,25,18,29.1,141.3,"TS"
198309,9,1983,8,25,18,26.6,128.7,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,26,0,30,141.2,"TD"
198309,9,1983,8,26,0,27.6,129.1,"TD"
198308,8,1983,8,26,6,31.2,141.3,"TD"
198309,9,1983,8,26,6,29,129.2,"TD"
198309,9,1983,8,26,12,30.3,128.9,"TD"
198309,9,1983,8,26,18,31.8,128.4,"TD"
198309,9,1983,8,27,0,33.3,127.4,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,27,0,9.8,183.2,"TD"
198309,9,1983,8,27,6,34.9,126.9,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,27,6,10.2,181.7,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,27,12,10.7,180.2,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,27,18,11.3,178.8,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,28,0,11.8,177.6,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,28,6,12.2,176.1,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,28,12,12.7,174.7,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,28,18,13.1,173,"TD"
198310,10,1983,8,29,0,13.1,171.3,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,29,6,13.2,169.9,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,29,12,13.2,168.5,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,29,18,13.1,166.8,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,30,0,13,165.1,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,30,6,12.5,163.7,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,30,12,11.9,162,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,30,18,11.4,160,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,31,0,10.9,158.4,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,31,6,10.5,156.9,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,31,12,10.3,155,"TS"
198310,10,1983,8,31,18,10.2,153,"TS"
```

The SN is the unique identifier, Y refers to Years,M --Months, D -- Days.
I would like to subset this data based on the unique identifier (SN) and between the following dates:

```
a). August 1 to August 10
b). August 11 to August 21
c). August 22 to August 30
```

I tried the following command but manually. I hope there is an easier way to do this in R.

```
test<-dat1983[which(dat1983$Month == '8' & dat1983$Day >= "10" & dat1983$Day <= "20"),]
```

If the unique identifier was already counted between August 1 to August 10, it should no longer be counted in the August 11 to August 21.Can anyone suggest how can I do this in R?

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create two sets of vectors with the 'days' and then do the subset with `Map` by comparing the corresponding elements of the 'vectors' to get a `list` of 'data.frame's.

```
d1 <- c(1, 11, 22)
d2 <- c(10, 21, 30)
res <- Map(function(x,y) subset(df1, M==8 & D >=x & D <= y), d1, d2)
lapply(res, head, 2)
#[[1]]
#      SN CY    Y M D lat lon   cat ID
#1 198305  5 1983 8 5   0 9.1 140.7 TD
#2 198305  5 1983 8 5   6 9.3 140.5 TD

#[[2]]
#      SN CY    Y M  D lat  lon   cat   ID
#25 198305  5 1983 8 11   0 20.6 130.7 Cat3
#26 198305  5 1983 8 11   6 21.2 130.8 Cat4

#[[3]]
#      SN CY    Y M  D lat  lon   cat ID
#80 198308  8 1983 8 22   0 22.2 137.9 TD
#81 198308  8 1983 8 22   6 23.2 138.7 TD
```

NOTE: In the dataset, there were only 8 column names for the 9 columns, so added the last column name as "ID".

Comment: If I have to apply this to pentad dates, how do I implement this in your code?. For example, January 1 to January 5 ...December 27-31 (Here's a list of pentads http://www.hysk.sakura.ne.jp/meteorol/misc/pentad.pdf). Many thanks,

Comment: @ichabod Please ask that as a new question.